# Selenium WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path' Исправление ошибки

Tags: python, selenium, cloudflare

У меня есть следующий код на python (selenium, undetected_chromedriver), написанный, чтобы автоматизированно получить доступ к сайту, защищенному сервисом cloudflare:

```py
import undetected_chromedriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

options = undetected_chromedriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
try:
    service = Service(executable_path='C:/Users/parto/Desktop/coinlist_reg/chromedriver.exe')
    driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
    driver.get("https://coinlist.co/register")
    time.sleep(15)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Однако как бы я не менял код, сколько бы ни пытался подобрать другую версию selenium и undetected_chromedriver для этого проекта, код выдает следующее исключение:

```
WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\parto\Desktop\coinlist_reg\venv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 800, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\parto\Desktop\coinlist_reg\venv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 755, in quit
OSError: [WinError 6] Неверный дескриптор
```

Я знаю, что аргумент executable_path не используется при создании объекта драйвера в селениуме версий 4.x. Но ведь я не передаю этот аргумент нигде в своем коде. Я задаю путь до драйвера обновленным способом, который должен работать в selenium 4.x, через аргумент service. Может, ошибка возникает из-за того, что undetected_chromedriver работает только с старыми версиями selenium (3.x), но при попытке переделать скрипт под selenium 3.3, во время установки библиотеки мне выдалась следующая ошибка:

```
undetected-chromedriver 3.4.7 requires selenium>=4.0.0, but you have selenium 3.3.0 which is incompatible.
```